# Can't kill a node process even after kill -9 PID

Tags: node.js, process

I have a node processing running on port 8080 and I get the `EADDRINUSE` error. I used `kill -9` to terminate the PID(s) on that port but every time I restart the server, a new PID comes up and produces the `EADDRINUSE` error again. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe some service is keeping the process alive, like PM2 for example.

Comment: I did have the forever process manager in my package.json but I removed it and it didn't change anything. Do you know how I can check if a service is keeping the process alive?

Comment: you can always call the CLI of the process manager to check what he's keeping alive.